# has anyone got Riak working on Solaris or OpenSolaris?

Tags: riak

has anyone got Riak working on Solaris or OpenSolaris? When I try to compile it I get:

```
user@opensolaris:~/riak# gmake all rel
./rebar compile
/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
gmake: *** [compile] Error 127

user@opensolaris:~/riak# mkdir /usr/bin/env
mkdir: Failed to make directory "/usr/bin/env"; File exists
user@opensolaris:~/riak#
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this question was answered on the riak-users mailing list here:

http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2010-February/000496.html

Comment: Yep, thanks, I got this working based on your reply.